# Retrieving value from wordpress database in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, wordpress

So I created a table in my database called inspirationWall with id and Visit_Count INT.
and added the row with id=1 and Visit_Count = 2.

Im trying to retrieve the value in Visit_Count in wordpress and display the value in an alert just for testing.

Ive been following the word press codex and used this example

```
<?php $user_count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users;" ) ); echo "<p>User count is {$user_count}</p>";?>
```

So by looking at that i made my code

```
var $inspirationWall_Count = 0;

$inspirationWall_Count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT Visit_Count FROM $wpdb-    >inspirationWall WHERE id=1;" ) );

alert($inspirationWall_Count);
```

It does not seem to retrieve the value and save it into $inspirationWall_Count.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an alert with php you have to do it with JS,

also you don't need to define again the `var $inspirationWall_Count = 0;` as its not working with php,

So here what you have to do,

```
$inspirationWall_Count = 0;
$inspirationWall_Count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT Visit_Count FROM $wpdb-    >inspirationWall WHERE id=1;" ) );
echo '<script>alert('.$inspirationWall_Count.')</script>';
```